# Pytest mock not targeting correctly

Tags: python, api, mocking, pytest

I am trying to mock a function call and assert that it has been called once. It seems to be targeting the correct object but for whatever reason, it seems that the calls are not being registered.

My test

```
@mock.patch('app.token_service')
def test_process_token_called(token_service_mock, app, client, db):
    token_response = client.post('/token', data=json.dumps(token_payload),
                                content_type='application/json')
    token_service_mock.process_token.assert_called_once()
```

The function being tested:

```
# app.py
from token_service import TokenService
from lib.db.Models import db

token_service = TokenService(db)

@app.route('/token', methods=['POST'])
def tokenize():
    try:
        req = request.get_json()
        card_number = req['card_number']
        expiry_date = req['expiry_date']
        return token_service.process_token(card_number, expiry_date)
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": e.message}, 400
```

I am expecting that `token_service.process_token` would be called at least once but running the tests produces the following:

`AssertionError: Expected 'process_token' to have been called once. Called 0 times.`

Perhaps I am not targeting it correctly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In your test code, is `app` a reference to the module containing your function being tested?

Comment: @TomDalton `app` is the file containing the `token_service` instance that calls the `process_token` method. So think that makes it is the module?

Comment: `token_service` is in the global namespace and has already been loaded when you patch it hence your mock never gets hit.

Comment: Further to the above comment, I think you probably want to do `@mock.patch_object(app, "token_service")`